# "I don't think this exists; here's 240+ maybes": acceptable answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

[Very Short Version: Answers should generally match [the scope](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) of their questions; most people are looking for one suggestion, not directions to the mall.]

When it was posted, [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25809/whats-a-good-jquery-based-content-slider) smelled a bit like [shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to me, but the size and CSS3 bits provided enough narrowing in that I didn't close/down-vote it, in case it went somewhere. In the end, the accepted response is an opinion that such a thing may not exist–though Jacob G came pretty close not long after–and a massive list(s) of options with no recommendations.

@toomanyairmiles defends the response.
I think at most it should've been a comment to the "I don't think it exists" effect, and minus the listicles altogether. It seems clearly a non-answer to me, but beyond that I fail to see how providing *several hundred* unqualified options is a useful response. My comment was meant to be taken literally: Kyriakos asked for a particular kind of needle and was instead pointed at several haystacks and told to start digging plus by the way I don't think the needle's even in there. That seems kind of insulting.

There's also a slope being greased here.
Nobody likes unanswered questions, but think of all the ones that could finally be closed out by a link to some site in the Envato network, or the front page of the WordPress plugin directory, etc. The answer's got to be in there *somewhere*. Maybe. Or not.

Update 3/6: And [here's another one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/26835/4502).

3/15: "[Here's two posts with 72+ maybes; I hope that helps](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27249/4502)."

Comment: Sure I could have phrased the answer better but it did nothing to justify the snippyness or the downvote IMHO. The answer was essentially there are 8,000,000 of these things - you've tried the two most popular so the answer is probably no. Here are some places to shop - really don't see the issue. I fully expected an admin to close the question to be honest.

Comment: @Su' Hi in regards to your Update on 3/6: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/26835/4502 since I got down voted for simply linking to codecanyon. I've updated my answer to link directly to a slider with auto height capability answering their question as direct as possible. Will that remove the down vote?

Comment: @Anagio (Getting settled back in from a trip.) Yes; this is precisely my point.

Comment: @Su' thank you, i'll be sure not to do that in the future and link directly to sources answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think "no, such a thing doesn't exist" is an acceptable answer. However I would like to see more evidence of research before I would be happy to accept it as an answer for one of my questions.

Comment: I agree that a researched no is acceptable. It's the stuff beyond the no here that I find problematic. It's precisely a display of *lack* of research.